Power latching circuit MOSFET is stuck ON
I've used a design I found online to for a power latching circuit.
My goal is to be able to shutdown the whole system using a pin on the MCU, and to turn it on by pressing a button.
User presses  button.
The code for the MCU keeps the pin HIGH as soon as it boots.
Use releases button.
MCU decides when shutdown is required, then drives the pin LOW.
Simulation accessible here
Circuit schematic, COMP1 is connected to the user physical button.
MCU capable of handling whole VBAT range (4.2-3.0V)


See this https://circuitcellar.com/resources/quickbits/soft-latching-power-circuits/

On the OP-linked page, the first schematic is ambiguous and the second schematic is incorrect.

What about the state of PWR_LATCH pin when MCU is OFF? Check if a resistor pulldown is needed.


Power latching circuit MOSFET is stuck ON

It's not stuck on. You've wired the P channel MOSFET incorrectly.

The body diode will always conduct giving you the impression that it is "stuck on".
The source should be connected to +VBAT and, the drain connected to +VSYS.

Thank you very much, that's brilliant. I didn't even notice as Falstad pre-places the FETs inverted... Godsend.
